# I need a vba code for display a rgb color for selected shape in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am a new for ppt vba, before i using only word record macro

I need help to get a rgb color for selected shapes in powerpoint 2013 by vba code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started:

```
Dim oSh As Shape
For Each oSh In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    With oSh.Fill
        Debug.Print .ForeColor.RGB
    End With
Next
```

Here's a routine for converting the Long returned by .RGB above to the R, G, B components. You need to here:

```
Sub LongColorToRGB(ByRef lRed As Long, _
    ByRef lGreen As Long, _
    ByRef lBlue As Long, _
    ByVal lRGBColor As Long)
' Note:  if long > 16777214, returns 255s for all three values
' Note:  be sure to dim your variables in the routine that
'        calls this sub

pRed = pRGBColor Mod 256
pGreen = pRGBColor \ 256 Mod 256
pBlue = pRGBColor \ 65536 Mod 256

End Sub
```

Comment: Sub FindRGBColor()
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim Red As Integer
Dim Green As Integer
Dim Blue As Integer
Dim tem As Single
For Each oSh In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    With oSh.Fill
    tem = (.ForeColor.RGB)
    Red = tem Mod 256
    Green = tem \ 256 Mod 256
    Blue = tem \ 65536 Mod 256
    MsgBox ("Red = " & Red & ", Green = " & Green & ", Blue =" & Blue & "")
    End With
Next
End Sub

Comment: I'd dim tem as Long rather than Single,but that looks about right otherwise.

Comment: Attached link doesn't work, kindly re upload proper one

Comment: @Chandraprakash See edited version above.